# How to compare date and time separately in postgres with php date-time value?

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework

I am doing my work in PHP and PostgreSQL with the Zend framework.

I have a date variable with a value of '2013-04-12'(Y-m-d format) and time variable with a value of '13:20:00'.

My date field and time field in the database table are separate.

How can I compare my PHP date and time with the datetime in a database table?

Comment: what you have done? show us code

Comment: what field types you have used for storing your date / time? date and ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you may select them as 1 field and compare it with correct timestamp value.

This can be used only if you have field types date and time!

```
$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , $time);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_field || ' ' || time_field  > '{$date}'";
```